# Not seeing line breaks in CSS code .load()ed via jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, line-breaks

I am using jQuery to .load() the contents of a CSS file into a div. But when the contents of that file are loaded, all the line breaks, tabs, etc. are gone. Is there a way to do a load of a css file while still preserving the line breaks?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of a `<div>` just use a [`<pre>` element](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_pre.asp) to preserve formatting, you can [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) into it the exact same way.

The default behavior of HTML is to display without line-breaks, extra white-space, etc (except in a `<pre></pre>`), [from the HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1):

> For all HTML elements except [`PRE`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-PRE), sequences of white space separate "words" (we use the term "word" here to mean "sequences of non-white space characters"). When formatting text, user agents should identify these words and lay them out according to the conventions of the particular written language (script) and target medium.

Comment: Geez, why didn't I think of that? That worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: I hadn't seen the "accept" function (I'm pretty new here) but have found it now. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get this issue myself:

```
$('<textarea>').load('./styles/style.css').appendTo('body');
```

I insert that into the page:

```
http://www.balupton.com/sandbox/jquery-sparkle/demo/
```

And it displays as expected.

The issue probably lays with the line endings used. The web uses `"\n"` while some versions of mac use `"\r"`, and windows uses `"\r\n"`.

**Or if you are trying to display it in a `DIV`,** you will have to use the CSS `white-space: pre;` to show the line spaces without converting them into `BR`s.

*Edit: forgot the dash in white-space.*

Comment: Thanks mate, glad I could help :-). Perhaps you would like to mark my answer as useful by voting it up (clicking the up arrow next to the answer), that will show it helped and give me a virtual pat on the back ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQuery plugin to syntax highlight too: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/